# Sample function to store and retrieve a p12 certificate in keychain - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, keychain

I need two functions one which stores the p12 certificate in iOS Keychain and the other function to retrieve the stored p12 certificate.

```
-(BOOL)addItem:(NSData*)item forKey:(NSString*)key {
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [self newItemDictionaryForKey:key];
[dict setObject:item forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
OSStatus ossstatus = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)dict, NULL);
if(errSecSuccess != ossstatus) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to add item for key %@ %ld request dict:%@",key,ossstatus,dict);
}
return (errSecSuccess == ossstatus);
```

}

To the above function i am sending the NSData that i get from p12 file.

Comment: When i tried to get NSData out of the p12 certificate and put it in the keychain it is not accepting it

Comment: "When i tried to get NSData out of the p12 certificate and put it in the keychain it is not accepting it" doesn't provide much indication of what you actually tried, how are folk going to help you figure out your problem? Show your code, describe the error. Help people help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to split this into two tasks:

1. Converting certificate from p12 data to `SecIdentityRef`. With this I can help
2. Store private key and certificate chain in keychain - [I'm struggling with this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771668/apple-keychain-store-client-identity-so-only-my-application-could-access-it), but I'm couple steps ahead comparing with you.

To perform a conversion, here is a code I'm using:

```
- (NSError *)setClientIdentityCertificateFromPKCS12Data: (NSData *)PKCS12Data withPassword: (NSString *)password
{
    OSStatus securityError = errSecSuccess;

    const void *keys[] =   { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
    const void *values[] = { (__bridge CFStringRef)password };
    CFDictionaryRef optionsDictionary = NULL;

    optionsDictionary = CFDictionaryCreate(
                                           NULL, keys,
                                           values, (password.length!=0 ? 1 : 0),
                                           NULL, NULL);
    CFArrayRef items = NULL;

    securityError = SecPKCS12Import((__bridge CFDataRef)PKCS12Data,
                                    optionsDictionary,
                                    &items);

    if (securityError == 0) {
        CFDictionaryRef identityDic = (CFDictionaryRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);

        SecIdentityRef secIdentity = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDic, kSecImportItemIdentity);
        CFArrayRef identityCertChain = (CFArrayRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDic, kSecImportItemCertChain);

        securityError = [self setClientIdentity: secIdentity withCertificateChain: identityCertChain];
    }

    if (optionsDictionary) {
        CFRelease(optionsDictionary);
    }

    if (items) {
        CFRelease(items);
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (securityError != errSecSuccess)
    {
        NSDictionary *info = nil;
#if !TARGET_OS_IPHONE
        NSString *errorDescription = nil;
        errorDescription = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)SecCopyErrorMessageString(securityError, NULL);
        if (errorDescription)
        {
            info = @{ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:errorDescription };
        }
#endif
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain
                                    code: securityError
                                userInfo: info];
    }

    return error;
}
```