# Apple keychain store client identity so only my application could access it

Tags: objective-c, macos, security, keychain

### Aim

I need to store client identity on OS X application in secure way in such way that only my application could access it. No prompting asking for permissions.

### Problem

Problem appeared immediately when I was trying to store client identity.
Here is code sample (what have I tied so far):

```
- (BOOL)saveClientIdentity:(SecIdentityRef)clientIdentity error:(NSError**) error
{
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
        (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly,
        (__bridge id)kSecValueRef:(__bridge id)clientIdentity,
        (__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag:[kMyKeychainAttrApplicationTag dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding],
        (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessGroup:kMyKeychainAttrAccessGroup
    };

    OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes, NULL);
    // status == -25299
    …
}
```

I'm constantly getting code -25299 and tool expalint the problem:

```sh
$ security error -25299
Error: 0xFFFF9D2D -25299 The specified item already exists in the keychain.
```

So it tries override global client identity (I never successful written a client identity for this application so there shouldn't be such conflict) and I don't what to do that.
It have to be private for only this application.

I verified what happens for respective loading code. It loads my developer identity and I do not want that.

```
- (SecIdentityRef)clientIdentity
{
    NSDictionary *attributes =
    @{
      (__bridge id)kSecClass:(__bridge id)kSecClassIdentity,
      (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly,
      (__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag:[kMyKeychainAttrApplicationTag dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding],
      (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessGroup:kMyKeychainAttrAccessGroup
      };

    CFTypeRef universalResult = NULL;
    OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes, &universalResult);
    SecIdentityRef result = (SecIdentityRef)universalResult;
    if (result)
    {
        CFAutorelease(result);
    }
    if (status != noErr)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load client identity: %@", NSErrorFromStatusErrorCode(status));
    }
    return result;
}
```

### Notes

I need to use same code for iOS, but here should be no problem since by default iOS keychain is not shared between applications.

Comment: Well, look at the error message. Read it. It should really be obvious. You can't add an item that already exists. There's SecItemUpdate.

Comment: Read again. I need application specific key chain. I never added this key chain. this is the first time I'm using that. Also when I changed value for kSecAttrApplicationTag it gives same result. I don't want to override global client identity I need client identity which will be used only by my application. Separate entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found nice solution.
The trick is to create custom key-chain and than store client identity in that key chain.

So basically there are tree steps.

1. First create or open custom key-chain:

   ```
   NSString *keychainpath  = self.customKeychainPath;
   unsigned char password[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
   GenerateCustomKeychainPassword(password);
   OSStatus status = SecKeychainCreate(keychainpath.UTF8String,
                                       SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH,
                                       password,
                                       NO,
                                       NULL,
                                       &customKeychain);

   if (status == errSecDuplicateKeychain)
   {
       status = SecKeychainOpen(keychainpath.UTF8String, &customKeychain);
       if (status == errSecSuccess)
       {
           status = SecKeychainUnlock(customKeychain,
                                      SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH,
                                      password,
                                      TRUE);

           if (status != errSecSuccess)
           {
               NSLog(@"%s Failed to unlock custom keychain: %@",
                          __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, NSErrorFromStatusErrorCode(status));
           }
       }
   }
   else if (status != errSecSuccess)
   {
       NSLog(@"%s Failed to unlock custom keychain: %@",
                  __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, NSErrorFromStatusErrorCode(status));
   }
   ```
2. Than add client identity to that key-chain

   ```
   OSStatus status = errSecSuccess;

   CFTypeRef  persistent_ref = NULL;
   NSDictionary *dict = @{
                          (id)kSecValueRef:(id)secItem,
                          (id)kSecReturnPersistentRef:(id)kCFBooleanTrue,
   #if !TARGET_OS_IPHONE
                          (id)kSecUseKeychain:(__bridge id)customKeychain,
   #endif
                          };
   status = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)dict, &persistent_ref);
   NSCAssert(status != errSecParam, @"Wrong contents of dictionary");
   if (status == errSecDuplicateItem)
   {
       NSLog(@"%s Item: %@ already exists", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, secItem);
       return NULL;
   }
   return (CFDataRef)persistent_ref;
   ```
3. And to read item from a keychain (`persistent_ref` can be stored in user defaults)

   ```
   NSDictionary *dict = @{
                          (id)kSecClass:(__bridge id)itemType,//kSecClassIdentity,
                          (id)kSecReturnRef:(id)kCFBooleanTrue,
                          (id)kSecValuePersistentRef:persistantRef,
   #if !TARGET_OS_IPHONE
                          (id)kSecUseKeychain:(__bridge id)customKeychain,
   #endif
                          };

   OSStatus status =  SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)dict, &result);
   NSCAssert(status != errSecParam, @"Invalid arguments");

   return result;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of success with SSKeychain, which was recently deprecated in favor of [SAMKeychain.](https://github.com/soffes/SAMKeychain/) It works for both iOS and Mac so it should address your cross-platform issue too.

Comment: Can't use third party libraries, It have to be Apple Keychain.

Comment: Also SAMKeychain documentation doesn't mention anything about client identity.